# Diffusion equation with insulated end

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the equation

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}
$$

with conditions

$$y(x,0) =  0 \quad \textrm{for} \ 0 < x < 1$$

$$y(0,t) = 1$$
and
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}(1,t) = 0 \ .$$

I understand that the general approach for a case like this is to consider a steady state solution which has the inhomogenous boundary conditions, and then use separation of variables with homogenous boundary conditions to get the rest (which will, I believe, be a Fourier cosine series).

If the final boundary condition were $U(1,T) = 0$, then clearly $1 - X$ would be a suitable steady state solution.

However, I'm having a great deal of trouble coming up with anything suitable for this case that won't mess up the differential equation itself (i.e it needs to disappear when differentiated twice wrt $x$?)

I've tried thinking about things of the form $a x + b$, and also trigonometric possibilities, but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when writing your answers. ;)

Comment: Hint: write $y(x,t) = 1 +u(x,t)$, and determine the problem for $u$.

Comment: I've actually tried this already, but it didn't seem to work. Using the boundary conditions, I end up with y(x,t) = 1 + sigma(An*exp(-n^2 * t * pi^2)*cos(n*pi*x)). Plugging in the T = 0 boundary condition, multiplying through by cos(mpi*x) and integrating from 0 to 2 (hoping to exploit orthogonality), I reach the unfortunate conclusion that A_n = 0...

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ in your first equation?

Answer (score 1):

You were correct to start with

$$ y(x,t) = 1 + u(x,t) $$

We obtain the BVP for the remaining part:

\begin{cases}
u_t = u_{xx} \\
u(0,t) = u_x(1,t) = 0 \\
u(x,0) = -1
\end{cases}

Separation of variables gives

$$ u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n \sin\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\pi x\right)e^{-(2n+1)^2\pi^2t/4} $$

You'll need to prove the orthogonality of the $x$-functions before getting to the final solution.

Comment: Thank you for this! I had been foolishly adjusting my boundary conditions incorrectly. Carrying out the rest of the calculation, I get An = -4pi/(2n+1). Would you mind confirming if that's correct?